# llvm: visitInstruction does not visit every instruction in a basic block?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to write a Simple pass on basic block and the code is as follows:

```
struct SimplePass : BasicBlockPass, InstVisitor<SimplePass>
{
   ... some initialisation and some finalization code 
    virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock& B) {
        std::cout << "---This is a block divider---" << B.size() << std::endl;
        visit(B);
        return false;
    }
    void visitInstruction(Instruction& I){
        std::cout << "Visiting every single instruction:" << I.getOpcodeName(I.getOpcode()) << std::endl;
    }
    void visitBranchInst(BranchInst& I) {
        if(I.isUnconditional()) {
            std::cout << "Encountered an unconditional branch!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

and very strangely I get some output like this:

```
...
---This is a block divider---5
Visiting every single instruction:call
Visiting every single instruction:load
Visiting every single instruction:add
Visiting every single instruction:store
Encountered an unconditional branch!
---This is a block divider---7 
Visiting every single instruction:phi 
Visiting every single instruction:load
Visiting every single instruction:sub
Visiting every single instruction:call
Visiting every single instruction:load
Visiting every single instruction:icmp
---This is a block divider---3
......
```

It is easy to see that in both blocks above the actual number of instructions should be 5 and 7, however the **visitInstrucion** function sometimes do not visit the last instruction of a basic block, why does this happen? Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Are you sure the last instruction in the block isn't a TerminatorInst instruction? (ie that doesn't represent actual code)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson aha I didn't know that before, thanks, I think I have solved the problem now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first block:

```
Visiting every single instruction:call
Visiting every single instruction:load
Visiting every single instruction:add
Visiting every single instruction:store
Encountered an unconditional branch!
```

It *is* 5 though! The last line comes from your `void visitBranchInst(BranchInst& I)` which takes precedence over `visitInstruction`. More specific visitors take precedence over more generic ones. If you want `visitInstruction` to be called anyway, you have to do it explicitly from more specific visitors - it won't happen automatically.

As for the next block, maybe it ends with a branch that is conditional? Then your `visitBranchInst` doesn't print anything, and doesn't propagate to `visitInstruction`.